# Programmatically moving a USB port between devices

Tags: usb

I have two devices that share data, the only common data access method they have is through a DOS formatted flash drive. When I'm at the office, I can easily plug into device A, add files, unmount, then plug into device B and extract files.

However, when I'm not physically there with the device, there's no way to remotely do this (device does not have a network connection, so I can't use FTP/SCP or NAS). The first thing that comes to mind is a USB hub that I can physically switch between connection to device A and device B. I can connect this to the network and send it a packet telling it to switch connections.

Does such a device exist? I don't want to have to go about designing one, but I feel like that may be my only option at this point.

**Edit: clarification.**

Device A and device B must both access files on a USB mass storage device (DOS formatted flash drive). What I do in the office is copy data from device A to flash drive, umount, unplug and plug flash drive into device B, then access files. I'm looking for a way to remotely do the unplug from device A and plug into device B step.

Comment: I'm not certain it's clear. Why not having devices A and B connected and you talk to each whenever you need ?

Comment: Possibly connected: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/507997/192882 - what you need then is a Linux device with two device porta

Comment: You might also look into KVM switches - most feature some USB ports to accommodate USB mouse and keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your note on designing one: there are ICs such as the [FSUSB42](https://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=FSUSB42)
which are controlled with a GPIO. Add any Linux board such as Raspberry Pi and done. Also - if you are using USB Full Speed don't bother too much with impedance, it's only 12 Mbit.